# Open folder in Visual Studio code in WSL with "code"

Tags: visual-studio-code, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My computer crashed and I had to reinstall my system today.
I'm running Windows 10 with VS Code and I'm using Debian (WSL) as my main terminal.

I have installed VS Code with the "Add to PATH" option and I have activated the Windows Subsystem for Linux in PowerShell.

I can use the command "code" in CMD and PowerShell but when I try to run it in Debian I get
`"-bash: code: command not found"`, as far as I understand it should work straight away when installing with the "path" option? At least according to this article: https://dev.to/ajeet/the-ultimate-guide-to-use-vs-code-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-51hc

I have also tried installing the "Remote Development" extension, but I'm still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following line to the `.bashrc` file in your `$HOME` directory (`~/.bashrc`).

```
PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/$USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin
```

Where you replace `$USER` with your Windows username.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create an alias and add it to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias $COMMAND"$PATH"
```

Where you replace `$COMMAND` with a name of your choice and `$PATH` with the path to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an alias in bashrc like:

```
alias code='code --remote wsl+<distro_name>'
```

Where `distro_name` is your WSL distro name.

You can check your distro name in PowerShell by using:

```
wsl --list
```

[Refer to the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl).